# C++ and Python libraries collaboration

Tags: python, c++, json

I am having two parts in my solution:

1. backend in C++
2. frotnend in Python

Communication is JSON over ZMQ.

I am thiking about compressing the JSON using gzip and passing it down to the backend compressed.

However,

I ran into a general problem:

I need the same compress/decompress library on both sides and in general this is true for every library that has output passed down to the backend.

I am thinking about the following options:

1. Find a library that has ports for both C++ and Python (native)
2. Find a C++ library and create Python bindings
3. Take Python standard gzip library and compile it using Cython for C++

Any thoughts ?

Comment: `gzip` is a compression _format_.  It shouldn't need the exact same library on both front-end and backend, so long as they both implement the `gzip` compression transformations correctly . . .

Comment: @mgilson - I agree that's basically true, but I think you would agree its best to even freeze the version of the library. even on the same format, the implmenetation varies...

Comment: As long as each implementation implements the format correctly, it doesn't matter that they're ultimately different code. Are you concerned that the browser you used to write the question is different from the one that I used to read it?

Comment: @univerio - actually browsers are a bad example.... site developers work very hard to support different browsers... every browser has its own variants... have you forgotton the "best viewed on internet explorer" ?
even though every browser implement the same HTML format and etc.
they are not the same

Comment: But you didn't write HTML. You wrote plain text. You'd be hard-pressed to find a browser that doesn't display the text you wrote as anything but the sequence of letters that you wrote.

Comment: Just to emphasize - i totally agree the zip problem can be solved.
i was thinking more about a *general* solution which can be used to solve the collaboration problem

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#module-zlib it's a standard python library based on the standard system library and generally you would use that library on the both sides of your app.

Comment: if you need a 'general solution' then probably there's no a definitive answer. for common tasks like parsing and generating some common formats like xml you may rely on the 'standard' solutions for a given platform, be it python, c++, or java, w/o bothering youself about particular implementations as long as these implementations fulfil you requirements about correctness, speed etc. In certain cases you may demand a specific implememtation which shares the code between Python and C++ but you should have good reasons for that, the reasons from your practical experience.